# Is there any problem with posting the same content on multiple Websites?

Tags: seo, backlinks, blog, blogger, articles

I find the same question on multiple websites but no one understands the question. means **If I create an article and publish on multiple websites, not on my original website**. just for backlinking.

I know the **issue** happen when first I publish an article on my website then share on other websites. But here I'm not going to publish an article on my website.

Comment: The problem is the same but not on your website. Other websites would have bad seo score due to duplicate contents and your website could suffer from bad/fake backlinks. That's why SEO directories ask you to write unique contents when you submit a website.

Comment: but if I add credit source URL in the bottom of articles

Comment: 1) Use rel="canonical" on the republished articles linking to the original article

2) On the republished articles link back to the original article and cite it as the original source

update
3) There's also a new Google meta tag that may help as well (http://googlenewsblog.blogspot.com/2010/11/credit-where-credit-is-due.html)

Answer (score 1):

I found out there is no problem to any website if you put nor complete article on another website. and also put the link of the original article in the bottom of the content you shared on multiple websites.

This technique I saw in one video of Neil Patel or Dean Brain.